# mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps: getting IDE to "see" the props

Tags: redux

**Problem: IDE does not resolve props passed to the component via connect()**

**Note**: this is not a bug, but an inconvenience to the coder

Say I have this React component connected to Redux via `connect()`:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            {this.props.someObject ? this.props.someObject : ''}
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        someObject: new SomeObject(state.someReducer.someObjectInfo),
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        // ...
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChatsList);
```

I'm using the IntelliJ IDE, and any prop connected to the component in the above manner, such as `someObject`, will get an **unresolved variable** warning. And if `someObject` has some properties/methods, they will neither be resolved nor show up in code suggestions (which are really helpful).

**A workaround**

1. Pass `state` and `dispatch` themselves as props:

   ```
   function mapStateToProps(state) {return {state};}
   function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {return {dispatch};}
   ```
2. Define my variables in the constructor (as opposed to via props):

   ```
   constructor(props) {
       this.someVar = props.state.someReducer.someVar;
       this.someObj = new SomeObject(props.state.someReducer.someObjectInfo;
   }
   ```
3. Update the variables manually whenever props change:

   ```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       someObject.update(nextProps.state.someReducer.someObjectInfo);
   }
   ```

The drawback is having additional boilerplate logic in `componentWillReceiveProps`, but now the IDE happily resolves the variables and code suggestion works.

**Question**

Is the workaround preferable? I'm using it, like it so far, and have not observed any other drawbacks thus far. Is there a better way to get the IDE to understand the code?

**Motivation (verbose; only for those interested in why I want to accomplish the above)**

The Redux tutorials show a simple way to connect state/dispatch to props, e.g.:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    users: state.usersReducer.users
    chats: state.chatsReducer.chats        
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    addUser: (id) => dispatch(usersActions.addUser(id))
    addChatMsg: (id, msg) => dispatch(chatsActions.addChatMsg(id, msg)
}
```

In the example above, the coder of a component will need to know every relevant reducers' names and their state variables. This can get messy for the coder. Instead, I want to abstract these details away from the component. One way is with a "module" class that accepts `state` and `dispatch`, and provides all get/set methods:

```
class Chats {
    // Actions
    static ADD_MESSAGE = "CHATS/ADD_MESSAGE";

    constructor(globalState, dispatch) {
        this.chatsState = globalState.chats;
        this.dispatch = dispatch;
    }

    // Get method
    getChats() {
        return this.chatsState.chats;
    }

    // Set method
    addChatMessage(id, msg) {
        return this.dispatch({
            type: Chats.ADD_MESSAGE,
            id,
            msg
        };
    }

    // Called by componentWillReceiveProps to update this object
    updateChats(nextGlobalState) {
        this.chatsState = nextGlobalState.chats;
    }
}
```

Now, if a Component requires the Chats module, a coder simply does this:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.chats = new Chats(props.state, props.dispatch);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.chats.updateChats(nextProps);
    }

    // ...
}
```

And now, all Chats get/set methods and properties will be available, and will be picked up by the IDE.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm trying with IntelliJ 2017.1 and unfortunately it still does not recognize props even after defining static propTypes.

Comment: I haven't been using React recently. As for a solution, see the original question under "Motivation". That workaround allows for IDE code suggestion. But, as pointed out in Kuznetsov's answer, passing global state in my custom class is a bad idea. So try to pass only the sub state.

Answer (score 0):

I think newest Idea can now understand component properties defined via propTypes and provides code completion for them. So you just declare propTypes. And it is not even a workaround, it's a good practice in my opinion.

```
class ChatsList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      someObject: PropTypes.shape({
        color: PropTypes.string,
        someFunc: PropTypes.func
      }),
      someDispatcher: PropTypes.func
    };

    render() {
        return (
            {this.props.someObject ? this.props.someObject : ''}
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        someObject: new SomeObject(state.someReducer.someObjectInfo),
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        someDispatcher: Actions.someDispatcher
        // ...
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChatsList);
```

Also, passing the entire state is a bad idea, since a component will receive props and get re-renderend if anything changes in the entire state (unless you provide `shouldComponentUpdate`)

Comment: So the `shape` definition must be manually updated if I make changes to `someObject's` method/property names? Is there a better way to define propTypes, something like PropTypes.class(Chats)?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure `shape` is a good alternative to Idea code suggestion, which has features like providing pop-up jsdoc, function parameter suggestions, etc. Since you mention passing the entire state as a bad idea, perhaps the Chats constructor simply takes in `state.chatsReducer` instead of `globalState`, so a re-render only happens when the chats sub-state changes (not perfect, but a good improvement)

Comment: From react docs: "You can also declare that a prop is an instance of a class. This uses JS's instanceof operator": `optionalMessage: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Message)`. Also I don't know if this will work with Idea autocompletion

Comment: Thank you for the `shape`, `instanceOf` suggestions. I also tried updating IntelliJ IDEA to the latest (2016.2), and the component still cannot resolve variables from `mapStateToProps`. I already have the `react-native-DefinitelyTyped`, `react-redux...`, `redux...` libraries. Either I'm missing some config or this approach does not seem to work.